# error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' my code is correct

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement a hash function and here is my code:

```
import BitVector
import glob


path = '/home/vguda/Desktop/.txt'
files=glob.glob(path)

hash = BitVector.BitVector(size = 32)
hash.reset(0)
i = 0

for file in files:
    bv = BitVector.BitVector( filename = file )
    while 1 :
          bv1 = bv.read_bits_from_file(8)
          if str(bv1) == "":
         break
      hash[0:8] = bv1 ^ hash[0:8]
      hash >> 8
      i = i+1 
hash_str = ""
hash_str = str( hash )
text_file = open("/home/vguda/Desktop/result.txt ","w")
text_file.write("Hash Code is %s" %hash_str)
text_file.close()

print hash
print (i)
```

The displayed error is:

```
"bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: The bash error indicates that the bash interpreter is trying to execute this instead of Python. Try running the script prefixed with python. e.g. >python myscript.py

Comment: The way you're executing it is wrong. The error message you get is from the linux shell `bash`, not from python; which means you're trying to execute the program in bash and not in python. Save the code as `somefile.py` and then run `python somefile.py` in the path where you saved it.

Comment: What command are you typing to run your code?

Answer (score 2):

First, perhaps this happened in copy and paste, but your indenting in your loop is all messed up, I'm not sure which blocks go where.

When you run things in the shell, you need to either tell python to run it:

```
python myscript.py
```

Or, put the following line as the first thing in your program to tell bash to run it as a python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Currently, bash is trying to run your python program as a bash script, and obviously running into syntax errors.

Comment: Looks like the OP has mixed tabs and spaces, hence the formatting